# Bootstrap-Colorpicker: Cannot set property 'colorpicker' of undefined

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I want to display an color picker in a form. I'm using [bootstrap-colorpicker](http://mjolnic.com/bootstrap-colorpicker/) and have build my colorpicker (ok, I have copied it from the advanced forms page from the [Admin LTE 2 demo](https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html)):

```
<!-- Color Picker -->
<div class="form-group">
     <label>Color picker with addon:</label>
     <div class="input-group colorpicker-critically">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" />
         <div class="input-group-addon">
              <i></i>
         </div>
     </div>
     <!-- /.input group -->
</div>
```

I initialise the plugin:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    //color picker with addon
    $(".colorpicker-critically").colorpicker();
});
```

And i link the `.js` before the `.css` in my `<head>` tag. jQuery is of course also included.

When I try the page I get the following errors:
[image: log from chrome]

Here is my `<head>` Tag:

```
<head><title></title>
<!-- bootstrap color picker -->
<script src="/plugins/colorpicker/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap Color Picker -->
<link href="/plugins/colorpicker/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/plugins/ionslider/ion.rangeSlider.min.js"></script>
<!-- Ion Slider -->
<link href="/plugins/ionslider/ion.rangeSlider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- ion slider Nice -->
<link href="/plugins/ionslider/ion.rangeSlider.skinNice.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/ion.rangeSlider.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/plugins/ionslider/ion.rangeSlider.skinFlat.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/plugins/ionslider//ion.rangeSlider.skinHTML5.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/plugins/ionslider/ion.rangeSlider.skinModern.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/plugins/ionslider/ion.rangeSlider.skinNice.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/plugins/ionslider/ion.rangeSlider.skinSimple.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/plugins/ionslider/normalize.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 


<!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.4 -->
<link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- FontAwesome 4.3.0 -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- Ionicons 2.0.0 -->
<link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- Theme style -->
<link href="../dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
     folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
<link href="../dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- iCheck -->
<link href="../plugins/iCheck/flat/blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- Morris chart -->
<link href="../plugins/morris/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- jvectormap -->
<link href="../plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- Date Picker -->
<link href="../plugins/datepicker/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- Daterange picker -->
<link href="../plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker-bs3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- bootstrap wysihtml5 - text editor -->
<link href="../plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you provide your `<head>` HTML part please ? As Bootstrap uses JQuery in its components it may require to put the JQuery before anything.

Comment: Post updated @Zeratops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bootstrap-colorpicker.js` need to be under the `jQuery` inclusion.

After doing this everything works fine.

Comment: What do you mean by under Jquery inclusion ?

Answer (score 1):

Your color picker library is conflicting that`s why your color picker function is not defined i have a another way to use color picker you can use directly

```
<input type="color" class="form-control" />
```

It will add color picker you don`t need to add a color picker library.

Comment: Yeah this works but it looks ... yeah terrible. Is there a way that I can use the bootstrap-colorpicker plugin anyway?

Comment: you can use this -- 
http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/colorpicker/   
or  http://mjolnic.com/bootstrap-colorpicker/

Comment: you have to use both js and css color picker library in bottom you can`t define on top..please try this ..

Comment: I have tried it and I still get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).colorpicker is not a function`, 
I'm using the second plugin you have linked (please take a look at my very first post).

Comment: Strange. I have copied the same code but in jsfiddle everything works... https://jsfiddle.net/9wpt2xdj/

Comment: Problem is still there. I have copied the code from my project and in jsfiddle everything works but not in my project @saurav garg

Comment: u have to put main bootstrap file on top then u have to put other libraries in this case u have 2 put color picker libraries in bottom ..do it then tell me..  js fiddle will work because it`s added library by default..

Comment: i think your all js files will be in footer section and it`s a header section you have to put css color picker library in header in bottom and js color picker library in bottom of footer file..........

Comment: i've put them in the footer and bootstrap to the very first position. still no reaction in my page

Comment: No other idea @saurav garg?

Comment: i have knowledge about them but you are doing something wrong..that i didn`t get..